# Edit default ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am looking for a way to access the XAML code for a default control in .NET Maui.

In WPF there was a Designer in the XAML view, where I could:
right-click the control - Edit Template - Edit a Copy...

This would give me the XAML for the control so that it was possible to modify the default templates provided by the framework.

Maui does not have the Designer so there is nowhere to click on a control. Is there another way to achieve this?

I am looking specifically for the XAML for the ProgressBar control.

As a sidenote, when looking at microsofts documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0
They show an example of the XAML for the CardView control.

Comment: In .`Net MAUI`, you want to achieve `XAML Editor Designer` feature supported in `WinForms` or `WPF`. However, this is an existing feature request: [Winforms like designer with optional hot reload xaml window #3439](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3439). You can follow up on that thread.

Comment: No. I dont want a designer feature. I just want a way to see the XAML that make up the default controls, so that I can copy it and make my own modified version of the control, like it was possible to do in WPF. Why dont you open up for this, instead of keeping it hidden? You did some good work with the default controls, so it makes no sense that I need to start from scratch because what you made cant be modified.

Comment: For now, I believe the `designer feature` as you said hasn't been implement. You can raise a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) in Github.

Comment: you are deliberately ignoring my question and giving a random non-related answer.

Comment: The docs you shared is about `custom control` consisting of different View objects. You can define your own controls and as far as I'm concerned, MAUI does not have the Xaml Designer.

Comment: you dont understand my question, its not helpful

Comment: You can [create a new discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/new) on Github to see if you can get some extra help there. Thanks!